# ArcGIS Polygon Volume - Variable height field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, volume

I'm using ArcMap 10.6

I have a TIN of a landscape which has a series of mounds on it. I have isolated polygons for each mound, which are not flat but variable in height as they go around each mound. I would like to calculate the volume and surface area for each mound, with the polygon for the mound treated as the reference plane.

I have tried the 'Polygon Volume' tool but this asks for an absolute height for the reference plane, not one which accounts for the differential height of each vertex in the polygon.